# Deploy android application. Missing 'installReleaseDebug' task for gradle

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle, react-native

I try to deploy release build of my application.

I describe in brief what I've done:
I've generated keystore file, set properties in build.gradle file for release configuration according this documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).
I got error message after command `react-native run-android --variant release`:

`Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project`

My build.gradle settings:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword "myKeyStorePassword"
            keyAlias "my-key-alias"
            keyPassword "myKeyPassword"
        }
    }
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Command `react-native run-android` deploys the build debug of my app w/o any problems. I would be glad any help.
Thank.

Comment: Try running `react-native run-android --variant=release` instead of `react-native run-android --variant release`

Comment: @FidanHakaj, thank you for response. I've already tried it, but there is same error.

Comment: @FidanHakaj, also after running command `gradle tasks` I see `installRelease` instead of `installDebugRelease`

Comment: The answer: you should use `configuration` option instead of `variant` since RN 0.39v was released

Answer (score 1):

Just `cd android && ./gradlew installRelease`